# How to install openssh-server on openSUSE?

Tags: ssh, opensuse, openssh, zypper

I recently installed openSUSE, and I want to set up an ssh server so that I can ssh into this machine. However, I am having trouble installing openssh-server.

I have tried

```
$ sudo zypper install openssh-server
```

This is what [this site](http://anl4u.com/blog/installconfigure-ssh-in-linux/) says to type, but I get this message:

```
Package 'openssh-server' not found.
```

On my *Ubuntu* machine, if I type

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

or on my *Fedora* machine

```
$ sudo yum install openssh-server
```

everything works fine.

How can I install `openssh-server` on openSUSE?  Do I have to manually add an RPM repository for it or something?

The solution doesn't need to use `zypper`, but I'd prefer not having to manually download and compile the source code.

Comment: If you see [documentation](https://nl.opensuse.org/OpenSSH): *In a normal openSUSE installation, the openSSH package is already installed.* The daemon is sshd.

Comment: @taliezin I believe you that openSUSE comes with openSSH pre-installed.  But it doesn't make sense that zypper can't find it.  How is the openSSH package supposed to be updated when necessary if the package cannot be found by the package manager?

Comment: what about 'openssh'?

Comment: Ah. So apparently the package goes by a different name in openSUSE than it does in Ubuntu and Fedora...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. openSUSE comes with openSSH pre-installed, so the ssh server does not need to be installed

   - https://nl.opensuse.org/OpenSSH
2. The packages for openSSH apparently have different names in openSUSE than they do in Ubuntu and Fedora (and maybe others?).

   - In Ubuntu (using `apt-get`) and Fedora (using `yum`), "openssh-server" is a valid package name
   - In openSUSE, the package "openSSH" covers both the SSH client and the SSH server

So if you type

```
sudo zypper install openssh
```

everything should work fine.  Though, as I said previously, it should already be installed. It will tell you if it's already installed.

Comment: "it should already be installed" => it's not true when using default image `opensuse` with docker. Anyway thanks for the answer, it was helpful, so you got +1 from me ;)

Comment: When I run that, I got `No provider of 'openSSH' found.`. I think the package is actually lower-case `sudo zypper install openssh`